# React: Send ref back to container component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a presentation component, which takes in a function from its container component as a prop. I want to return a `ref` as an argument with the function back to the container component. But it is returned as `undefined`.

(What I want to achieve is to send the email address the user insert into the form in the presentation component, back to the container component so I can process it there.)

Any suggestion on how to make this work?

**Container component**

```
class EmailInputContainer extends Component {
  addEmailToList(childComponent){
    console.log(childComponent.refs)
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <EmailInputView addEmailToList={this.addEmailToList}/>
    )
  }
}
```

**Presentation component**

```
const EmailInputView = (functions) => (
  <Grid style={Styles.emailInputView.container} verticalAlign='middle'>
    <Cell width='5/12' style={Styles.smallText('black', 1.1, 1.5, 'left')}>
      <p>Enter your mail and we'll keep you<br />posted with news and updates!</p>
    </Cell>
    <Cell width='5/12' align='right'>
      <form onSubmit={functions.addEmailToList(this)}>
        <input style={Styles.emailInputForm.emailInput} ref='emailInput' type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" />
        <input style={Styles.emailInputForm.submitButton} type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </Cell>
  </Grid>
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imho best practice would be to pass an onchange handler from as prop to your EmailInputView like:

```
class EmailInputContainer extends Component {

   handleChange: function(event) {
      this.setState({myEmail: event.target.value});
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <EmailInputView onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
      )
   }
}
```

and:

```
<input onChange={this.props.onChange} style={Styles.emailInputForm.emailInput} type="text" />
```

in the EmailInputView itself. Works with

```
<form onSubmit={this.props.onChange}>
  ...
</form>
```

too (havent checked the event u might have to adjust the handler in the EmailInputContainer  slightly).

In this case u dont have to pass a ref which fits much better with the philisophy of react. Imho you should never ever pass a ref the way u wanted to and only use refs in the component you are in when there is no other way.

Optinal (if u dont want to submit the form):

```
class EmailInput extends Component {

  onChange(event) {
     this.setState({myEmail: event.target.value});
  }

  onSubmit() {
     this.props.onChange(this.state.myEmail); //u should rename the prop i just named it so it fits with the example of the parent component above
  }

  render() {
     return (
        <Cell>
           <input onChange={this.onChange} />
           <button onClick={this.onSubmit} />
        </Cell>
     );
  }

}
```

there is no need to use a form at all if you dont want to prevent its functionalitly afterwards. If u still want to post the data without page reload u have to implement an Ajax call anyways.

Comment: Nice, thank you. Why call the function for every keystroke (`onChange`) and not only `onSubmit`? How do I listen for the submit button in this solution? And how do I preventDefault (I tried `event.preventDefault()` with no luck)?

Comment: im not sure which data u get on onSubmit but of cause it would be better to do use this because u would need it anyways to know when the form actually was submitted and u dont handle strings containing the half email all the time. give it a try.

Comment: i was just to focued on passing a handler instead of a ref - because thats the important point to get imho

Comment: y do u want to prevent default?

Comment: Thank you, I will try `onSubmit`. I want to `preventDefault` so the site don't reload when I click `Submit` button.

Comment: in that case u should go for the second solution i added now and implement an ajax request - i think there should be plenty of other questions on stackoverflow how to implement a ajax call

Comment: plz considder marking my answer as solution in case you think it was helpfull - i would appreciate some reputation to spend as bounty on some of my own questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your presentation component, capture the `ref` node through a callback function when it renders, then pass the node value back to your parent on submit.

```
let inputNode

const EmailInputView = (functions) => (
  <Grid style={Styles.emailInputView.container} verticalAlign='middle'>

    ...  

    <Cell width='5/12' align='right'>
      <form 
        onSubmit={() => functions.addEmailToList(inputNode.value)} <-- update here
      >
        <input style={Styles.emailInputForm.emailInput} 

          ref={node => inputNode = node} <-- this is what you want

          type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" />
        <input style={Styles.emailInputForm.submitButton} type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </Cell>
  </Grid>
)
```

Then update your handler:

```
addEmailToList(value){
  console.log(value)
}
```

So this solution is great especially when you don't have a parent that's handling anything, such as dispatching a redux action directly from the component that has the input field. However @Aligertor's answer is spot on.