# Accessing child component refs from within a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a simple React app that loads movie data from the OMDb API based on a search -- so far, so good.

However, I refactored the app and added the data fetching logic in a parent *container component*. Now I'm having trouble accessing the search field's value via `refs` from within the *container component*.

My component hierarchy looks like this (each component in its own file):

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13HaI.png)

The `state` and `props` seem to be fine and are being passed correctly. This is the JS for the main component -- I'm using axios to fetch data from the API:

```
class MovieSearchContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Search: [] 
    };
    this._performSearch = this._performSearch.bind(this);
  }

  _performSearch() {
    var _this = this;

    let query = I WANT TO ACCESS THE SEARCH FIELD VALUE HERE, maybe?;

    this.serverRequest = 
      axios
        .get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${query}&r=json`)
        .then(function(result) {    
          _this.setState({
            Search: result.data.Search
          });
        }) 

    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Application query={this.state.Search}
                   onSearch={this._performSearch} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MovieSearchContainer />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Then, further nested, I have a `<SearchForm />` component with the following JS:

```
class SearchForm extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state={
      searchText: ''
    };
  }

  _onSearchChange(e) {
    const searchText = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ searchText: searchText });
  }

  _handleSubmit(e) {
    if (e) e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSearch(this.state.Search);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="search-form" onSubmit={this._handleSubmit.bind(this)} >
        <label className="is-hidden" for="search">...</label>
        <input type="search" 
               onChange={this._onSearchChange.bind(this)}
               name="search" 
               ref="query"
               placeholder="Search a Title..." />
        <button type="submit" id="submit" className="search-button">...</button>
      </form>      
    );
  }
}
```

The big question is: How can I access the `ref` (or value) of the `input` inside `<SearchForm />`, from within `<MovieSearchContainer />`, so that I can pass that value into the API call?

```
 // MovieSearchContainer

  _performSearch() {
    var _this = this;

    let query = I WANT TO ACCESS THE SEARCH FIELD VALUE HERE, maybe?;

    this.serverRequest = 
      axios
        .get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${query}&r=json`)
        .then(function(result) {    
          _this.setState({
            Search: result.data.Search
          });
        }) 
  }
```

Should I place this logic elsewhere?

I've tried methods like `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.query).value` and a few others, but no luck.

Please let me know if you need me to provide more code. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: Send ref back to container component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595888/react-send-ref-back-to-container-component)

Comment: It seems all your components has `onSearch` property you are passing from top to bottom. And `SearchForm` is passing the value up the component tree. You simply need to add corresponding argument to `_performSearch(query)`.

Comment: Thanks! But it looks like that still returns as `undefined`.

Comment: let the parent add the ref and then access it via `this.refs` in the parent.
where ever you pass in `<SearchForm ref='query' />`  then access using `this.refs.query`

Comment: Wouldn't that point to the component instance instead of just the DOM node?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I was passing the same `ref` value to each child component, including the `input` I was trying to target. For example:

```
// component hierarchy
<Application />
  <Header onSearch={this._performSearch} ref="query" />
    <SearchForm onSearch={this.props.onSearch} ref="query" />
      <input ... ref="query" />
```

I was calling `this.refs.query.value` in the *container component*, which only targets the outermost element of the rendered child component.

So instead, I passed a different `ref` value for each component, including the `input` node:

```
<Header onSearch={this._performSearch} ref="header" />
  <SearchForm onSearch={this.props.onSearch} ref="searchform" />
    <input ... ref="query" />
```

Then, in my `_performSearch()` method, I targeted the `input` value like this:

```
_performSearch() {
  var query = this.refs.header.refs.searchform.refs.query.value;
  this.serverRequest = 
    axios
      .get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${query}&r=json`)
      ...
}
```

It works great, but seems a bit code smelly. Any cleaner suggestions? :)